# MatIconModule no longer compiles in libraries

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-package-format

I'm trying to use the `MatIconModule` in a Angular Package Format library and when I introduce the `MatIconModule` it fails to compile.  To see for yourself clone the MVCE repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:fireflysemantics/maticonmoduleerror.git
cd maticonmoduleerror
npm i
ng build --prod fs-assets
```

This is what the module looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [MatIconModule
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class FsAssetsModule { }
```

If `MatIconModule` is removed, it compiles.  Angular Material was added to the root project the standard way with `ng add @angular/material`.  These are the compiler errors:

```
> ole@mkt:~/Temp/clone/maticonmoduleerror$ ng build --prod fs-assets
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point '@fireflysemantics/assets'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✖ Compiling TypeScript sources through NGC
ERROR: projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:64 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                  ~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:69 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                       ~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:82 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                    
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:83 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                     ~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:85 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                       ~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:55 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'abstract'.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                         ~~~~~~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:78 - error TS2693: 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                ~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:88 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                          ~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/optgroup.d.ts:16:22 - error TS2420: Class '_MatOptgroupBase' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type '_MatOptgroupBase' but required in type 'CanDisable'.

16 export declare class _MatOptgroupBase extends _MatOptgroupMixinBase implements CanDisable {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/disabled.d.ts:12:5
    12     disabled: boolean;
           ~~~~~~~~
    'disabled' is declared here.
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/icon/icon.d.ts:60:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatIcon' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.
  Type 'MatIcon' is missing the following properties from type 'CanColor': color, defaultColor

60 export declare class MatIcon extends _MatIconMixinBase implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, CanColor, OnDestroy {
                        ~~~~~~~

An unhandled exception occurred: projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:64 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                  ~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:69 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                       ~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:82 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                    
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:83 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                     ~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:85 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                       ~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:55 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'abstract'.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                         ~~~~~~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:78 - error TS2693: 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                ~~~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:88 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                          ~
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/optgroup.d.ts:16:22 - error TS2420: Class '_MatOptgroupBase' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type '_MatOptgroupBase' but required in type 'CanDisable'.

16 export declare class _MatOptgroupBase extends _MatOptgroupMixinBase implements CanDisable {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/disabled.d.ts:12:5
    12     disabled: boolean;
           ~~~~~~~~
    'disabled' is declared here.
projects/fs-assets/node_modules/@angular/material/icon/icon.d.ts:60:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatIcon' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.
  Type 'MatIcon' is missing the following properties from type 'CanColor': color, defaultColor

60 export declare class MatIcon extends _MatIconMixinBase implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, CanColor, OnDestroy {
                        ~~~~~~~

See "/tmp/ng-14VpXS/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

This used to work fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22720

Comment: Did you try updating to Angular 12?

Comment: @JSONDerulo ( Cool name :) ) I tried upgrading both the CLI and Node, so now I have the latest version of both running.  I still get the same errors.

Comment: Did you also to update the project itself with `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli @angular/material`? Because in the linked repository I see that Angular 11 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is still using Angular 11, see the `package.json` in the linked repository. Updating to Angular 12 using `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli @angular/material` should fix the issue.